# Is there a parameter I can provide to a Postgres connection string to "name" a client?

Tags: postgresql

We have a postgres database which a lot of scripts connect to. Crucially, there is *not* a username per-script; there are a (small) number of usernames which are shared around the place.

When doing troubleshooting or performance optimising, it would be very useful to know which server SQL process corresponds (or corresponded, past-tense) to which script.

I am thinking of something like:

```
host=db-server dbname=whatever clientID=script1.py
```

I suspect the answer is "no", but my google-fu is weak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explore using the ["application_name"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-APPLICATION-NAME) parameter. Depending on what your code is doing you can log it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. It seems to be new in Postgres 9, and we're still on 8.4 unfortunately.

Comment: It's also a bit of a shame that it doesn't update the process title but then you can't have everything!

Comment: It is logged in the log file by default which should give you the backend pid.